# Assigning integer value to a Float wrapper in Java

Tags: java, boxing

The following works

```
float a=3;
```

but the following doesn't:

```
Float a=3;
```

Shouldn't 3 be automatically promoted to float (as widening conversions don't require an explicit cast) and then Boxed to Float type ?

Is it because of a rule I read in Khalid Mogul's Java book ?

> Widening conversions can't be followed
>   by any boxing conversions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why `Float a=3;` won't work is because the compiler wraps the `3` into it's Integer object (in essence, the compiler does this: `Float a  = new Integer(3);` and that's already a compiler error). Float object isn't and Integer object (even though they come from the same `Number` object).

The following works:

```
Number a = 3;
```

which in essence is translated by the compiler as:

```
Number a = new Integer(3);
```

or as Joachim Sauer mentioned,

```
Number a = Integer.valueOf(3);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually auto-boxing is the equivalent of `Integer.valueOf(3)` and not of `new Integer(3)`. The difference is that the former does some caching of common values.

Comment: Thanks. 3 is translated as Integer.valueOf(3) but What happens when we typecast 3 as (Float) 3 ? Is Float.valueOf(3) is called now ?

Comment: @Daud, nope....Autoboxing is done by the compiler, so in essence, the compiler will do this: `Float a = (Float)Integer.valueOf(3);` which is still an error.

Answer (score 2):

```
Float               Integer
  ^                    ^
  |                    |
  |                    |
  v                    v
float <----------->   int
```

There is a boxing/unboxing conversion betwen the primitive and the wrapper, and there is a promotion from one numeric primitive to another. But Java is not able to make this conversion twice (convert from int to Float, in your case).

Answer (score -1):

Float a= 3.0f;  will work.

Comment: Nice. I asked this to encourage responders to first prove their answers before posting it. It gives a sense of relief to those reading your answer.